# Omnicontacts rails facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

We are using Omnicontacts gem for facebook,gmail contact import. It is working for gmail contact import.But for facebook, always the contact details are empty.

I added the following

Controller:
contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']
Initializer:
importer :facebook,ENV['facebook_client_id'],ENV['facebook_secret_key']

I created a Facebook application & added contact email , domain details and changed "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" this status and YES.

Anyother setup I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that all your code and setup are working fine.

If your app was created at Facebook on or after April 30th 2014, your app won't be able to call v1.0 of the API.

In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.

In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app.

More info in Facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids